# NGINX Conditional TCP proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have a Proxy configured as below:

```
stream {
    upstream redis_server {
        server 10.XXX.X.XX:6379 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s;
        server 10.XXX.X.XX:6380 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {
        listen 6378;
        proxy_pass redis_server;
    }
}
```

We want all the requests to be forwarded to 6379 , only if its unavailable it should be forwarded to 6380.

Answer (score 0):

Use `server 10.XXX.X.XX:6380 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s backup;`

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/#server-weights